# When I look at the log in tortoise why are some of the files for each commit highlighted?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am trying to search through history on a folder with tortoise git. I found what I want but annoyingly I cant figure out what the difference between rows that are highlighted and rows that aren't for each commit. It's tricky to explain but here is a screen shot...

[image]

You can see the highlighted rows are more red, why? (Apologies about the obfuscation it's a sensitive project).

Thanks

Comment: I *think* what happened is your did a show log on a sub directory of your repository. Tortoise shows all changes in the entire commit, and highlights those that were specific to the directory you did your show log on.

Comment: And I think you have the right answer. I figured this soon after asking. Can you write an answer and I will award you? Up to you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you show the commit log in tortoise, it shows the entire commit for all paths. What's happening is you did a show log on a sub directory, so tortoise is highlighting the files that were affected in that directory.